# How to take my belongings when moving to a new country?

Tags: luggage, brazil, sweden

I'll move from Brazil to Sweden, and therefore will take a LOT of luggage (desktop computer, clothes, notebook, etc.), that probably wouldn't fit in a single bag.

What's the best way to take my belongings with me, taking into account security and money?

---

I heard its possible to put my desktop computer in a different bag and send it to Sweden. Is this a feasible solution?

Comment: Although the OP is moving permanently to another place, this question falls under the Travel part not under the expats part, IMO..

Comment: @NeAnDerthal: Exactly my thoughts when considering whether this should go on expats or travel.se

Comment: Since it's about shipping your stuff, which travellers don't have to do on such a scale, but expats regularly have to do, it's better on the expats site. I've been travelling since 1989 to sixty countries and never tried to bring a desktop computer with me (-:

Comment: @hippietrail: Maybe you should vote for this to be moved then? I don't know what's the process for moving a question to another SE.

Comment: @JLagana: OK I flagged it for moderator attention asking them to migrate the question to expats.SE - I *think* that's the proper way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, while it relates to travel (kinda), people who post on expats are likley to know mor eabout it.

Answer (score 7):

Long haul shipping, if you want to move your household items. This tends to be either slow and not very cheap, or reasonably fast and quite expensive. Typically, these services would be paid for by your employer. One company that does long haul shipping (and which I've used in the past, with satisfaction) is http://www.go2uti.com.

If you just want to move more than would fit in one checked in bag, but not too much more, strongly consider paying up for traveling with an extra bag. Expensive per kilo, but fast and easy.

Do keep in mind that 'expensive' items, like electronics, tend not to be covered by an airline's insurance, when shipped as checked in luggage.

Comment: yes, extra baggage will probably be cheaper and better survive the journey when sensitive equipment is involved. The excess books or clothes can be send using regular sea mail, and sometimes by sharing a container with someone else.

Comment: I don't have the references at hand but I remember of the expression "freight carrier"... "haul shipping" is new for me and apparently includes railroad transportation. Anyway, never done it, but a friend received all her belongings from Europe at Brazil via ship carrier. If not mistaken after certain Kilos air transport is not an option. IMO, security and electronics should be dealt at air level, never by sea.